# New to Python requests library, getting '[Errno 61] Connection refused'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I've searched high and low and can't find a fix that seems to fit my use case. I've had some Python3 install issues on my M1 mac but think it's now running okay.

Just trying to learn / work with the [requests library](https://2.python-requests.org/en/master/), but when I try to run [this](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/python-api-tutorial/) very simple python code:

```
import requests

response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/this-api-doesnt-exist")
print(response.status_code)
```

I get the below error...

Any advice on how to fix this? I'm pulling my hair out.

Thank you!

```
/Users/myname/venv/python310/bin/python /Users/myname/Documents/2022_api/api01.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 703, in urlopen
    httplib_response = self._make_request(
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 386, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 1040, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 358, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 186, in _new_conn
    raise NewConnectionError(
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10f5a0850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 440, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /this-api-doesnt-exist (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10f5a0850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myname/Documents/2022_api/api01.py", line 3, in <module>
    response = requests.get("https://api.open-notify.org/this-api-doesnt-exist")
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 75, in get
    return request('get', url, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/api.py", line 61, in request
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 529, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 645, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/myname/venv/python310/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 519, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.open-notify.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /this-api-doesnt-exist (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x10f5a0850>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 61] Connection refused'))

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: The actual website is `http://api.open-notify.org/this-api-doesnt-exist` it is not an `https` site but rather an `http` site

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Connection Refused means that the host (`api.open-notify.org`) is not listening on the port (https is on port 443) in your request.

I tried connecting to port 80 (plain http) instead and that worked for me:

```py
>>> response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org/this-api-doesnt-exist")
>>> print(response.status_code)
404
```

For laughs, I tried connecting to the base url

```
>>> response = requests.get("http://api.open-notify.org")
>>> print(response.status_code)
500
>>> response
<Response [500]>
>>> response.text
'<html>\r\n<head><title>500 Internal Server Error</title></head>\r\n<body bgcolor="white">\r\n<center><h1>500 Internal Server Error</h1></center>\r\n<hr><center>nginx/1.10.3</center>\r\n</body>\r\n</html>\r\n'
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Wow, so simple. haha